# How do I use JQuery in my Wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have searched for an answer all over, but nothing has worked for me so far.

I have tested the jQuery code outside of Wordpress and it seems to work, so I think I am having a problem registering or enqueuing the js file

I want to use Jquery in a wordpress plugin I am writing. I tried to register and enqueue it with the following code:

```
function my_script() {
    wp_register_script('my_script', plugins_url('js/my_script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script' );
```

But this for some reason is not working.

The Jquery code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.test').css("background-color", "red");

});​
```

I also tried: `jQuery$(document).ready(function(){` and `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

But nothing seems to work.

EDIT: I went to see my source, and what I get is the follwing, which I don't know is correct as I am quite new to wordpress..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/same-hight.js?ver=1.1"></script>
```

Please help.

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){// CODE HERE });`  would actually work make sure your browser is not caching a copy of the JS

Comment: Does the JS file actually get enqueued with the correct URL? Verify that the script appears in you source and the src is correct.

Comment: Also post anykind of error message since that would pretty much narrow it down for us.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers :-). I will check all the above. @Musk - I dont receive any error message. All I see is that when i open my js file and edit the file within wordpress is that it is inactive... but my css file is also inactive and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jQuery(doc...` is the correct approach but you weren't passing `$` into the function which is why it wasn't working for you.

Change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.test').css("background-color", "red");

});​
```

To:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.test').css("background-color", "red");

});​
```

Comment: Thank you @Nathan Dawson. I will try it out as soon as I get the chance

Comment: I just tried it out, but it still does not seem to work for some reason. I mate an edit in my post with what I get when I check the code with F12 in Google Chrome. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Finally it worked, there was something wrong with the jquery code :s (lame). But the way it worked is how you suggested. :) so +1 and answer accepted :)